# Passing data into a partial view with a jQuery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a view called Index that has a list of links, each with an ID. When one of those links is clicked, I want a jQueryUI dialog box to open and show that ID. (The dialog box will eventually have an HTML form in it, but for the sake of simplicity, let's just start with printing the link ID.)

So far, I've tried to make the content of the dialog box a partial view (since eventually it will be complex). My Index view looks like this:

```
// Index
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#dialog-wrapper').dialog({
            width: 380,
            height: 270,
            modal: true
        });

        $('.action-link').click(function() {
            $('#dialog-wrapper').dialog("open");
        });
    })
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Link.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (UserLink userLink in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => userLink.Link.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="action-link">click here</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<div id="dialog-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_Dialog")
</div>
```

So the question is, how do I pass the ID of the clicked link to the partial view? I know I can add another parameter to the @Html.Partial call, but how do I pass the ID corresponding to the link clicked?

Comment: you will load partial view at run time via ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something such as

```
// Index
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#dialog-wrapper').dialog({
            width: 380,
            height: 270,
            modal: true
        });

        $('.action-link').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //stop the hyperlink from trying to navigate
            var theId = $(this).attr("data-linkid");
            $('#dialog-wrapper').dialog("open", theId);
        });
    })
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Link.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (UserLink userLink in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => userLink.Link.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="action-link" data-linkid="@Html.Raw(userLink.Link.Id)">click here</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

This could write your "id" into a pseudo-attribute on the hyperlink which is then accessible as an attribute using jQuery within you action-link click method.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. But how do I access theId in my partial view?

Comment: In the dialog method I assume there is a way to pass state? I'm not familiar with that method. Worst case you could use the "data" property of #dialog-wrapper e.g. $('#dialog-wrapper').data('linkid',theId); And then retrieve in Partial with script var theId = $('#data-wrapper').data('linkid'); Just because your partial view is loaded late doesn't mean it cannot access other elements on the page using jQuery selectors e.g. #data-wrapper should still be accessible in script

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly you need but it does helps you i guess, it shows the ID of that particular Grid Row, so in your case use the same button to get the ID, Check this fiddle(copy this link)

//jsfiddle.net/m8fsv/23/